# Trying to use eslint to help me, but all I get is errors - Configuration for rule "endOfLine" is invalid

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, prettier

I have followed the advice of using ESlint, because it's suppossed to be helpful, when writing firebase functions code.

However, even the helloWorld function that is initialized by firebase is giving me errors?

Prettier and ESlint is conflicting as well - prettier adds spaces between brackets, but ESlint doesn't like that and again giving me errors?

I thought that I could fix this conflict by following this guide - https://dev.to/s2engineers/how-to-make-eslint-work-with-prettier-avoiding-conflicts-and-problems-57pi

But again I got this error, that I don't know what `endOfLine` rule supposed to do, but its giving me error -

```
Error: ../.eslintrc.json:
        Configuration for rule "endOfLine" is invalid:
        Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '"auto"').
```

my .eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ["airbnb-base"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["prettier"],
  rules: {},
};
```

Am I missing something or ESlint is not helpful at all, why does spacing between brackets matter?

Answer (score 0):

ESLint is definitely helpful, and personally I've never noticed a conflict between prettier and eslint. The question of bracket spacing is purely aesthetic if you ask me, and personally I prefer the idea that aesthetic questions are the domain of formatting (prettier), whereas best practices for the composition of the code itself is the domain of linting (eslint).

Concretely: I don't know what rules you're getting from airbnb-base, i'm not familiar. But I suggest you start with the recommended value for `extends` for a typescript project, something more like:

```
[
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
]
```

I'm thinking `env` and `parserOptions` are specific to your project so I'm not including those. Nonetheless ... I don't believe you really need the `prettier` plugin.